# Best Material icons to use for authorisation

Tags: authorization, google-material-icons

Hi i am using material icons and polymer. I want to use certain icons to show actions i.e. login, register and log out. I'm confused which icons to use. Any help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the set of icons in [`iron-icons`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-icons), the following might be appropriate for your use case:

*login*

[image]
[image]
[image]

*logout*

[image]

*register*

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Usage

1. Pick an icon from the [`iron-icons` list](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-icons).
2. Import the appropriate icons into your HTML head (i.e., `iron-icons/${ICONSET}-icons.html`, where `${ICONSET}` is indicated in the icon name before the colon). Note the `icons` set is located in `iron-icons.html`.

   ```
   icons -> iron-icons/iron-icons.html
   social -> iron-icons/social-icons.html
   places -> iron-icons/places-icons.html
   ...
   ```
3. Enter the icon's name into the `icon` attribute of a Polymer element, such as `<iron-icon>` or `<paper-icon-button>`.

   ```
   <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
   <iron-icon icon="icons:exit-to-app">

   <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/social-icons.html">
   <paper-icon-button icon="social:person-add">
   ```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/social-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/editor-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:exit-to-app"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:exit-to-app</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:lock"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:lock</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:lock-open"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:lock-open</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:lock-outline"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:lock-outline</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:supervisor-account"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:supervisor-account</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:verified-user"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:verified-user</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:account-circle"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:account-circle</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:account-box"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:account-box</span>
  </div>
    <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:fingerprint"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:fingerprint</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:assignment-ind"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:assignment-ind</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:perm-identity"></iron-icon>
    <span>icons:perm-identity</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="social:person"></iron-icon>
    <span>social:person</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="social:person-add"></iron-icon>
    <span>social:person-add</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iron-icon icon="editor:mode-edit"></iron-icon>
    <span>editor:mode-edit</span>
  </div>

</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JKdZqe?editors=1000)</sup>